# Angular Material button works, but does not look Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

So, I am just starting to use Angular Material.

I added two buttons and a slider to my new app:

```html
<button class="mat-button"  color="accent">An Angular Material button</button>
<hr>

<a mat-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
<hr>

<mat-slider min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1"></mat-slider>
```

The slider slides and the Google button launches a new tab with Google, when clicked. However, the buttons do not look material:

[image]

I am not going to post the full app (yet). I have been following the [official documentation](https://v5.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), which is straightforward enough, and the fact that the slider & Google button work should show that I have probably set it up almost correctly.

The only problem being, of course, the appearance of the buttons.

As per the docs, I have added `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` to my `styles.css`. I also tried removing the tilde, which had no effect.

I don't know if this bit is a distraction, but I looked at the [AM Themes documentation](https://v5.material.angular.io/guide/theming) which suggested an alternative of adding

```html
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to my `index.html`. But, that gave an error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

As I said, that is maybe a distraction, because I created my project from the CLI.

- ng nw
- ng add @angular/material

I have a file `material.module.ts`

```js
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatSliderModule} from "@angular/material/slider";

const materialModules =  [MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule,];

@NgModule({
  imports: materialModules,
  exports: materialModules,
})
export class MaterialModule{}
```

and, obviously, I import that into my `app.modules.ts` (***after*** `BrowserAnimationsModule`, as per the Getting Started docs linked above).

Any idea what I might be doing wrongly, or do you need the complete code (or just certain files)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the attribute '**mat-raised-button**' to your button.

Here is the reference to [Angular Material buttons](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) for more attributes.

```
<button class="mat-button" mat-raised-button  color="accent">An Angular Material button</button>
```

Here is the working example in the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-amqv1n?file=src/app/app.component.html).